# Difference between memory and register

Tags: memory, assembly, cpu-registers, instructions, mov

I saw assembly code like,

`MOV [EAX], EBX`

the above line, They are mentioned `[EAX]` is memory and `EBX` is Register. So, here what is the difference between `[EAX]` and `EBX`. What will happen in above instruction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this syntax, brackets around a register means a memory location is used (as source or destination, according to the instruction) with starting address specified at the register (EAX in your case). For example, if EAX contained 1344 before the instruction, value from EBX is copied to logical memory addresses 1344-1347 (because this is 4 byte copying).

I hope this is enough to untangle them in your mind:) and please notice more complex cases are possible (e.g. `MOV [EAX+ECX],EBX` forms destination address as sum of two register values).

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that the first 16 bytes in memory starting at address 0x1000 contains the following:

```
0x1000: 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
```

Now let's say that `EAX` contains 0x1002 (just an example; don't try to write to arbitrary addresses in real code) and `EBX` contains 0x12345678.

`MOV [EAX],EBX` would write the value of `EBX` (which is 32 bits == 4 bytes) to memory starting at the address contained in `EAX`, so afterwards the memory would look like:

```
0x1000: 00 01 78 56 34 12 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
```

Note the order in which the bytes were written. This is because x86 processors are little-endian.

If you had done `MOV EAX,EBX` you would have copied the value 0x12345678 to the register `EAX` and left the memory at 0x1002 unchanged.

Comment: I have doubt on changing values in 0x1003 to 0x1005. Why its changing ? As per, assembly code its changing?

Comment: Because `EBX` is 32 bits (4 bytes).